# What is the lagrangian of Einstein field equations

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism

What is a lagrangian such that Euler-Lagrange equation (not sure if it's correct form for this case)

$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}=\partial_\lambda\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\lambda g_{\mu\nu})}.$$

Gives us Einstein field equations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is almost certainly answered elsewhere, but the Hilbert Action, from which Einstein's equation can be derived, is:

$$S = \int d^{4}x\;\left(\sqrt{|g|}\frac{1}{16\pi G}R + \mathcal{L}_{m}\right)$$

taking the variation is pretty complicated (there are second derivatives of the metric in the action, and you have to deal with gauge invariance) and best looked up in a textbook, though.  But note, that by this definition, we define $T_{ab} = \frac{\delta \mathcal{L_m}}{\delta g^{ab}}$

Comment: The Wikipedia page does a pretty good job as an introduction of walking through the variation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action. Also, if it is not clear, the action is an integral over $d^4x$.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to add a general matter Lagrangian to that as well, since the Einstein field equations are usually formulated with the presence of a stress-energy tensor. The sign difference between them and the general arbitration in the overall choice could also be emphasized.

Comment: So the lagrangian is just $\mathcal{L}=\frac{\sqrt{|g|}R}{16\pi G}$?

Comment: @JavaGamesJAR yes

Comment: @JavaGamesJAR Excluding the $\sqrt{|g|}$ which is just the volume element for your spacetime manifold, yes, that is the purely gravitational Lagrangian.

Comment: @rhomaios I agree that the factor of $g$ just comes from the volume element, but it also influences the variation, and whether it "counts" as part of the lagrangian depends on whether you are looking at GR as "pure" geometry or as a field theory.

Comment: I'd also argue that it is easier for a beginner to think about it as "part of the Lagrangian" since you DO have to vary it no matter what your persepctive is.

Comment: The reason why it influences the variation is because the E-L equations as formulated above are not fundamental, they are derived from the principle of least action. The action does have the entire integral, hence you need to vary everything, including the volume element. Absorbing the volume element into the definition of Lagrangians would make it easier on the face of it for beginners, but it would create a great deal of misunderstandings in regards to how integrals are defined on a curved manifold. Sooner or later, they will need to start thinking in terms of non-Euclidean geometry.

Comment: Similarly, if you define the matter Lagrangian in the same guise as you suggest, it implies that they somehow encode information about the geometry of spacetime in them which then complicates that definition. Plus, it would affect the definition of the stress-energy tensor as you wrote it.

Comment: Really defining the volume integral means defining the theory of forms, which is usually beyond the scope of a first-year GR course.

Comment: That's true, fair enough.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer I am looking at it as field theory, so I should exclude this term?

Comment: @JavaGamesJAR it's there, irrespectively of adding it.  it's just a matter of what the thing that you call "the gravitational term in the action" is, the whole action is as written above, no matter what.

Answer (score 4):

With the cosmological constant $\Lambda$ included, the *Hilbert action* for empty space is
$$S = \frac{c^4}{16 \pi G} \int   (R-2 \Lambda)   \sqrt{-g} \, \mathrm{d}^4 x. $$

Wikipedia calls it the Einstein-Hilbert action, but this is wrong. The action is due to Hilbert, not to Einstein.

Comment: Notice that this action does not yield the stress-energy tensor on the right-hand side of Einstein's Equations

Comment: Indeed, as stated, it is only for vacuum; matter can be added as above.